# Angular 1.4 and using ngAnimate with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to setup a ngAnimate `.animation()` script with Angular 1.4 but I am struggling with the basics as this should display an alert but it does not :

```
.animation('.animated', function () {
     // should display an alert here...
     alert('hello ?');
})
```

I must be missing something but can't figure out what.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonsaysHi/5ve89622/).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" /> Is Visible...
        <span class="animatedsomething" ng-show="checked">Hello {{who}}.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.who = 'World';
})
.animation('.animatedsomething', function () {
       // should display an alert here...

    alert('hello ?');

});
```

seems to generate the alert. Not sure why. Quoting from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations "AngularJS 1.3 provides animation hooks for common directives such as ngRepeat, ngSwitch, and ngView, as well as custom directives via the $animate service.", may be you need one of those directives for the animation to be applied.

Comment: Thanks ... in fact I was expecting the animation() function to be run on module init. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Animation is triggered using one of directives described here [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations). For example `ngClass`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ve89622/3/).

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <span ng-class="{animated: true}">Hello {{who}}.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```